# Load nodes partially?

Tags: entities

Is there a way to partially load nodes based on the view mode? Say I've got a lot of fields, but for the list view I need only 3 of them ... node_load fetches them all, which doesn't make sense. Or does it? I think about using computed_fields, but when it comes to larger lists I'm a little concerned about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7), or to go a bit more advanced (and more 'meta'), use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) (see examples [here](http://drupal.org/node/916776)).

But, if you're doing this outside of a loop or something, it's often easiest to do a full node_load(), as you can just grab more fields out of there when you need to (in the future) without having to add a bit more code.

My rule of thumb is this: if I only need to load one or two nodes for a particular operation, and the node doesn't contain more than 10-15 fields, I'll just do node_load(). Much more convenient when you don't need to worry about the extra 50ms or so... (for smaller node objects, of course. It's different if you have a node with 25 fields attached!).

[Edit: Just realized field_get_items() still requires the node object itself... which defeats the purpose.]

Comment: All true, as long as data comes from standard fields. I am searching for generic way to correlate data from other systems (other databases, web services ... whatever) with entities. Computed fields seem to be very powerful, but I don't wan't fire a http-request if I don't even need the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you could make use of `node_reference` and split your node type into multiple linked "sub-types"? That would make it possible to simply `node_load()` those parts that you need to work with at any point.